# excel vba type mismatch- comparing values w/ combination of "right", "offset", "len"

Tags: vba, excel, compare

why might the following return a type mismatch error?

```
Dim Arrow As Workbook
If wb.Name Like "*Arrow*" Then
Set Arrow = wb
dplastrow = activeworkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows(Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
LastArrow = Arrow.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

For Each account In activeworkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("D11:D" & dplastrow)
For x = 2 To LastArrow
If (Trim(Right(account.Offset(0, 1), Len(account.Offset(0, 1) - 2))) = Arrow.Worksheets(1).Cells(x, "BL")) Then
'some action
```

I was able to vlookup and return it's matching value in the actual excel gui no problem. I've tried enveloping the cells in cstr(, val( and/or affixing them with .text to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a blank cell (or text with a length less than 3)) in the next column that is returning a len of -2 to the Right function?

Comment: Or do any of the cells have errors in them?

Comment: LastArrow = Arrow.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(**Arrow.**ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

Comment: you are right sir, thanks! Pertaining to the existence of cells with length<3

Comment: Yeah, I <3 length as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to arbitrarily take the length of the value from one cell to the right, you need to ensure that there is sufficient text to subtract 2 from the length.

```
Dim Arrow As Workbook
If wb.Name Like "*Arrow*" Then
    Set Arrow = wb
    With wb.Worksheets(1)
        lastArrow = .cells(.rows.count, "BL").end(xlup).Row
    End With

    dplastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows(Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    For Each account In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("D11:D" & dplastrow)
        For x = 2 To lastArrow
            If Len(account.Offset(0, 1)) > 2 Then
                If (Trim(Right(account.Offset(0, 1), Len(account.Offset(0, 1) - 2))) = _
                    Arrow.Worksheets(1).Cells(x, "BL")) Then
                    'some action
                End If
            End If
        Next x
    Next account
End If
```

You should get away from relying on ActiveSheet for worksheet references (see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)) and there are better ways of determining the last row in Arrow's column BL.